# Generate bounding boxes from elevation map/watershed transform

Tags: image-processing, scikit-image

I am using scikit-image to perform image segmentation on some images I have, and I was referring to this tutorial (https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/tutorial_segmentation.html)

I am using the elevation map method described and although I am not able to get correct result after applying watershed algorithm, the elevation map itself seems good enough for my purpose.

I am getting this output when I plot the elevation map:

[image]

Now I want to get the coordinates for the bounding box for this object. How do I achieve this? I looked at http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_contours.html but I am unable to figure out how do I choose the second argument for `find_contours` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
from skimage import filters
from scipy import ndimage as ndi

threshold = filters.threshold_otsu(elevation_map)
binary = (elevation_map > threshold).astype(int)
bounding_box = ndi.find_objects(binary)[0]
```

Comment: Thanks. I get two tuples, can't find documentation as to what format the numbers are in.

Comment: You should get two *slices*, which correspond to the slices needed to extract the bounding box. ie if you do `image[bounding_box]`, you'll get the shoe back. If you want the actual values, `bounding_box[0].start`, `bounding_box[0].stop` tell you the start row and end row, while `bounding_box[1].start` and `bounding_box[1].stop` tell you the start column and end column.